# Error sending emails with Mailgun using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I am trying to send an invitation email to my Laravel Web App, in which some parameters also have to be passed. Im not able to send an email and guess the problem is not with my configuration. Can someone help me on this?

This is my form to send the invitation to an email:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'AdminUserController@store']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="is_active" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="house_id" value="{{Auth::user()->house->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="role_id" value="2">
    <div class="form-group' has-error' : '' }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Email']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Invite', ['class'=>'btn-primary small']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is router:

```
Route::post('/admin/user/store', 'AdminUserController@store')->name('admin/user/store');
```

This is the controller function responsible for all the logic AdminUserController@store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
            'title'=>'Invitation',
            'content'=>'You are invited to try Housing Around App',
            'is_active'=> $request->input('is_active'),
            'house_id' => $request->input('house_id'),
            'role_id'=>$request->input('role_id'),
            'email'=>$request->input('email')
            ];

    $to = $data['email'];

    Mail::send('users.user.create',$data, function ($message){
        $message->to('to', 'Housing Around')->subject('Invitation');
    });

    return redirect('home');
}
```

These are my configuration for Mailgun:

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox**************************.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=44****************************************c
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxf6**************************.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-4******************************0
```

my mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@housingaround.io'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Housing Around App'),
],
'username' => env('postmaster@sandbox*********************.mailgun.org'),
'password' => env('44**************************c'),
```

my services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('sandbox*******************.mailgun.org'),
        'secret' => env('key-4*************************0'),
    ],
```

Still, it doesnt work. Am i missing something?

Blade file

```
<html>

<head>


</head>
<body style="background: black; color: white">

<h1>Housing Around Invitation</h1>

<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: As im using Jquery Mobile it doesnt show any error but on my laravel.log it says: local.ERROR: Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [to] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Housing_around/

Comment: What email address are you using for your ‘to’?

Comment: I think you overwrite the TO email address by using: $message->to('to', 'Housing Around')... @LuizWynne

Comment: Whatever comes from the form as  a request. That's what im passing as the addres to be sent to

Comment: try use $to instead of 'to'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $to instead of 'to' and then let the anonymous function know about it.

```
function ($message) use ($to)
```

Comment: im doing like this

Comment: $to = 'luwynne@aol.co.uk';//$request->input('email');


        Mail::send('users.user.create', $data, function ($message) use ($to, $data) {
            $message->from('info@housingaround.io', 'Your Application');

            $message->to($to, 'Housing Around')->subject('Invitation');

            return redirect('home');

        });

Comment: I dont have the errors anymore nut for some reason it stops executing on the store view and doesnt send the email and dont bring me back to the view i was expecting. Any sugestions?

Comment: Don't send data through USE, if you are not using it.

Comment: Put the redirect after Mail::send();

Comment: you don't need a return statement there.

Comment: Check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail, it is exactly what you.

Do you have any error or exception ?

Answer (score -2):

try to run after changing .env file

```
php artisan config:cache
```